# Angular JS Plugin installation on Eclipse Helios giving error will installing

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add Angular js plugin in my Eclipse Helios. 
I am using install via new software tab under help tabs.

URL using -  http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/1.2.0/ from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse/help.

After trying to install following error is coming

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Debugger Support for Nodeclipse 1.2.0.201606160856 (tern.eclipse.ide.debugger.nodeclipse 1.2.0.201606160856)
  Missing requirement: Tern - Eclipse 0.6.0.201410042051 (tern.eclipse 0.6.0.201410042051) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Tern - Eclipse 1.1.0.201511082254 (tern.eclipse 1.1.0.201511082254) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Tern - Eclipse 1.2.0.201606160856 (tern.eclipse 1.2.0.201606160856) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Tern - Eclipse - Core IDE 0.6.0.201410042051 (tern.eclipse.ide.core 0.6.0.201410042051)
    To: bundle tern.eclipse 0.2.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Tern - Eclipse - Core IDE 1.1.0.201511082254 (tern.eclipse.ide.core 1.1.0.201511082254)
    To: bundle tern.eclipse 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Tern - Eclipse - Core IDE 1.2.0.201606160856 (tern.eclipse.ide.core 1.2.0.201606160856)
    To: bundle tern.eclipse 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Debugger Support for Nodeclipse 1.2.0.201606160856 (tern.eclipse.ide.debugger.nodeclipse 1.2.0.201606160856)
    To: bundle tern.eclipse.ide.core 0.0.0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Helios (3.6) is too old for this software you need to install something newer such as the current release Eclipse Neon (4.6).

In the error log the text

```
requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0'
```

is saying that the minimum version of SWT required is 3.7.0, Eclipse Helios only has version 3.6 so is not compatible.